# Eevee - Volume Scatter shader doesn't render but shows on preview

Tags: volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

I also tried baking indirect light with a light probe and, the volumetric option in the render tab is activated but I still couldn't figure out how to make it appear also on render.
Maybe it's not possible yet?
Thanks for the help!